# how to auto scale the application according to different devices in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I had created an winform application its working good, but the problem arises when I had opened that application in an different device, as the screen resolution varies the application gets stuck, is there is any code to auto scaling by itself. But I don't want to resize every time. I had developed the application entirely in windows forms in c#,.net frame work.

Comment: Define *different device* and *gets stuck*. If you're talking about DPIAwareness and virtualization, see [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103).

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to set the parameter for the form WindowState = Maximized